# How to get data(VALUE) of current point from trackball in SfChart?

Tags: xamarin.forms, syncfusion

I use SyncFusion SfChart for Xamarin.Forms. How get information from trackball?

How can I get data of current point in trackball.I want to get point and write it in Label.But I need to get value of current point.How to get this 20 value on image?

[image]

Trackball will be activated once you long-press anywhere on the chart area and when I move my finger the information in trackball changed.How can I get it?Because I want to write it in Label.Text

Comment: [TrackballCreated](https://help.syncfusion.com/xamarin/charts/trackball#trackballcreated) - "The TrackballCreated event occurs when the trackball moves from one data point to another. This argument contains object of ChartPointsInfo. The following properties are available in ChartPointInfo class to customize the appearance of trackball label based on condition.".   "DataPoint - Gets the respective underlying object of the data in which trackball is activated."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the trackball label text by using TrackballCreated event in SfChart as per the below code example.

**CodeSnippet:**

```
<chart:SfChart TrackballCreated="SfChart_TrackballCreated" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">

. . .

</chart:SfChart>


private void SfChart_TrackballCreated(object sender, ChartTrackballCreatedEventArgs e)
{
    foreach(var trackballInfo in e.ChartPointsInfo)
    {
        // Get or set the trackball label text
        var trackballLabelText = trackballInfo.Label;
        trackballInfo.Label += "%";

    }

    rectangleAnnotation.X1 = (e.ChartPointsInfo[0] as ChartPointInfo).XPosition;      
    if (!rectangleAnnotation.IsVisible)
    {
        rectangleAnnotation.IsVisible = true;
        var seriesBounds = (sender as SfChart).SeriesBounds;
        rectangleAnnotation.Y1 = seriesBounds.Top;
        rectangleAnnotation.Y2 = seriesBounds.Bottom;
        rectangleAnnotation.X2 = seriesBounds.Right;
    }
}
```

Also, we have attached the sample for your reference. Please find the sample from the below link.

**Sample:** https://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/general/ze/ChartSample_Trackball_modified-637580766

For more details, please refer the below link
https://help.syncfusion.com/xamarin/charts/trackball#events